# How to push back altered variables into a tensorflow graph?

Tags: tensorflow

I am trying to manipulate the weights of a multilayered LSTM RNN by first extracting the trainable variables in a session, like so:

```
    variables_names =[v.name for v in tf.trainable_variables()]
    values = session.run(variables_names)
```

Now the variable `values` is a list of all weights and biases in my tensorflow graph. After some arithmetic operations to the weights and biases, I would like to upload them back into the graph to continue training the RNN. Does anyone know how to do this? I thought if I use the numpy list `values` as a source for re-initializing the graph it would work but I have been unsuccessful. I've tried the following methods till now:

```
init = tf.constant(values)
tf.get_variables(variables_names, initializer = init).run()
```

and

```
init = tf.constant(values)
session.run(tf.variables_initializer(values))
```

In both these cases the code finishes executing abruptly by printing values I want to initialize back into the graph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables have a .load() method. You can pass your updated values back to the graph this way.

Comment: The issue I have with the load method is the name of the variable I have retrieved from `variables_names =[v.name for v in tf.trainable_variables()]` are of type `rnn/multi_rnn_cell/cell_0/lstm_cell/weights:0`, therefore I am unable to access the variable with this name. Could you please demonstrate with an example as the example given in the tensorflow documentation does not help with my question.

Comment: Create a 2nd list: `variables = [v for v in tf.trainable_variables()]` You can then use the .load() method on any element in that list. It will be in the same order as the list you created (which is a list of strings).